# How to make HTTP request in windows service?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, service

i want to implement my first windows service application.
this app must run day and night. it should to send each 1 hour http request with possibility to make snapshot of requested webpage and save it in database.

can you show me some c# code examples how to:

1. make http request from windows service.
2. set a timer for requesting each 1 hour.
3. send e-mail that snapshot is successfully saved in DB.

thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please explain what specific problem you are having. you have a outside shot of getting a full project coded for you.

Comment: Writing code is your job and nobody here will do it for you.

Comment: i just wanted to know which classe or stuff like that do i need. i dont need full coded application. dont worry Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp and The Scrum Meister

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following 3 MSDN pages should get you started.

1. Make HTTP Request: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx
2. Working with timers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=VS.100).aspx
3. Emailing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

Comment: Glad to help! If you haven't installed the MSDN locally, it can be a big help when looking up names of classes or things you want to do. Or, you could set up a search shortcut in your browser for just the MSDN.

Comment: Helps you to learn about screen shot. Create a Win Service and send the URL along with your request to whom you want to take the back up..
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34831-taking-a-screen-shot-in-c%23/