# How to get data from Windows Service to WEB Application?

Tags: vb.net, web-applications, serial-port, windows-services

I've Windows Service that Interacts with Weighing Machine and gets the results into txt file. Instead of that I want to receive that data into my web application. My Service code is as Follow.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
    ' in motion so your service can do its work.
    lg.WriteToLog("------------Service Started!-----------------")
    Try
        myPort.PortName = "COM2"
        myPort.BaudRate = 9600
        myPort.Parity = Parity.None
        myPort.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One
        myPort.DataBits = 8
        AddHandler myPort.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceived
        myPort.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        lg.WriteToLog("Error Occurred while Initializing Serial Port !")
        lg.WriteToLog(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    Try
        If myPort.IsOpen Then
            ReceivedText(myPort.ReadExisting())
            lg.WriteToLog("Port is open and getting the data!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        lg.WriteToLog("Error Occurred while reading data!")
        lg.WriteToLog(ex.ToString)
    End Try    
End Sub Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
    lg.WriteToLog(output([text]))
End Sub`
```

Can anyone Suggest me how to get the same data send back to WebApplication as I am fresher with web applications, I've tried googling it but did not found any useful answer. Here output is just a simple function that performs conversion of weight in correct format so you can ignore that one !

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Web API and send your data to that web api and from there you can use it.

Update: Check this [How to make HTTP request in windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826216/how-to-make-http-request-in-windows-service)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Sir thank you for your response, it would be great if you can provide me way how to do it.

Comment: I have added a link, please follow it.